# Passing Generic's to React Typescript Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

My goal is to get the `any`'s out of the Props of my columns and data.

I know there is a way to make data be something like `T[]` and then render can be something like `(record: T) => void`.

Does anyone know how to do this or any documentation that could help?

### Component

```
interface Props {
    columns: {
        title: string;
        render: any;
    }[];
    data: any;
}


export class Table extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return <div>Render Something</div>
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
<Table columns={[{title: "", render: record => record.name}]} data={[]} />
```

Comment: [Does the official documentation on Generics help?](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Comment: @VLAZ Not really. I've been trying to implement it using these docs but it's just not getting through. Because it has to do with React Props it's just really confusing. I've been trying to find component & Props examples I'm pretty stuck

Answer (score 1):

I cannot remember where I read about this, but as you also think it should be possible to define generics in components. And below you can find how I managed it.

**Definition:**

```
interface Props<T> {
   data: T
}

export function Foo<T>({ data }): React.PropsWithChildren<Props<T>>: React.ReactElement | null {
   return (
      <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
   )
}
```

**Usage:**

```
...
<MyComp<{ foo: string }> data={{ foo: 'value' }}/>
or
<MyComp<MyType> data={{ foo: 'value' }}/>
...
```

**EDIT:** Some documentation about the solution lies here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#generic-type-arguments-in-jsx-elements

Answer (score 0):

The only information about T in your post is that it has a `name` field, so:

```
interface Props<T> {
    columns: {
        title: string;
        render: (record: T) => void;
    }[];
    data: T;
}

interface MyCustomType {
   name: string
}

export class Table extends React.Component<Props<MyCustomType>> {
    render() {
        return <div>Render Something</div>
    }
}
```

```
<Table columns={[{title: "", render: record => record.name}]} data={[]} />
```

But your render function in the usage returns something (whatever the type of `record.name` is), not `void`.

Also, it looks like `data` is an array (so maybe `T[]`?), not a `T`.

So, it looks more like this, to me:

```
interface Props<T> {
    columns: {
        title: string;
        render: (record: T) => string;
    }[];
    data: T[];
}

interface MyCustomType {
   name: string
}

export class Table extends React.Component<Props<MyCustomType>> {
    render() {
        return <div>Render Something</div>
    }
}
```

If you don't know what the type of `MyCustomType` is, you will have to make it `any`.

If you want a Table that can be instantiated as a "Table of ", then you can do this:

```
export class Table<K> extends React.Component<Props<K>> {
    render() {
        return <div>Render Something</div>
    }
}
```

That's how you would do it with straight-up Generics. Not sure if you can put this in your TSX though:

```
<Table<MyCustomType> columns={[{title: "", render: record => record.name}]} data={[]} />
```

You might need to do:

```
MyTable = Table<MyCustomType>

<MyTable columns={[{title: "", render: record => record.name}]} data={[]} />
```

Comment: My only confusion is we never know what `MyCustomType` is because `data` could literally be any object structure. What would I do then? I tried `React.Component<Props<T>>` but it doesn't seem to like that

Comment: You mean it is... `any`?

Comment: I guess I was just confused what generic actually was. I thought there was a way to use generic in place of an `any`

Comment: You can use a generic to say: "some specific type that will be supplied when this is used in code somewhere". It's kinda an "any for now"